# Maven (commandline): No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, windows, command-line, environment-variables

```
Failed to execute goal or.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:comple <default-compile> on project google-play-services: Compilation failure

No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

This is the result when using the Android SDK Deployer from the commandline in Windows. I added `JAVA_HOME` `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45` to my system variables.

Did I configured the wrong parts?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was very easy to solve. I only had to restart the commandline after changing the system variables.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @TuGordoBello close the commandline window and start another commandline.

Answer (score 33):

This error can also happen if you install a new version of JAVA (JRE), because the Java installer change the order of environment variables on Windows.

So, verify the `PATH` values in the *System Variables*. If you see the:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Or:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

On the top of the list, edit the `PATH` and change the order of the previous paths to stay **below** to the JDK path variable (per example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin`).

Comment: I don't understand this. What is first and what is second?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts You can find the first or the second entry in your System Variables. Just make sure that them are **below** to the JDK path variable in the list of variables, because Windows will get the first one that it will found in the list. and you want the JDK one first.

Answer (score 26):

Normally this happens, compilation of the source cannot be done from JRE(Runtime Environment) its for running the compiled code.

So first thing should done is validating JAVA_HOME path defined in environment variables.

it should be directed to JDK.
eg:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Comment: JAVA_HOME was the problem for me. Even if you put the jdk's bin folder in the PATH variable, mvn still uses the JAVA_HOME instead.

Comment: Excellent. JAVA_HOME must be a requirement for compiling projects with particular versions of maven on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I run my spring boot project in vscode, I stumbled on this same issue.
Adding this to my pom solved it

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: worked for me in my VS code ANTLR project with Maven :)

Answer (score 0):

While setting `JAVA_HOME` on windows os use `Progra~1` instead of `Program files` since it has space in between e.g. `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_251`

Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'

Answer (score 0):

Moving the JDK Bin path to the top in the list of Environment Variables, fixed the problem.

[image: JDK Bin path moved to the top in the list of Environment Variables, fixed the problem.]

Comment: Please [edit] to make more obvious what additional insight you contribute, especially beyond the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922882/7733418 because curretnly this post gives the impression of only being "thanks".

Answer (score 0):

The java.com [download](https://www.java.com/en/download/) page says "Download Java"

[image]

If this is the JRE and not the JDK. This is confusing.

The link downloads as, `jre-1234`. So this is the JRE.

There seems to be another download on oracles home page (that forces you to login) and one on [openjdk](https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads).

There is a faq on the openjdk page:

> **How Do I Download Java JDK?**
> You can download Java JDK 8 and 11 by
> scrolling up on this page and selecting the version you need from
> OpenLogic.

If you type `javac` in the command line and get `the command is not found` the java compiler is not installed.